# (Beginner) Why is this not correct?

Tags: python

```
#Add the input number 4 times. Ex. 3+3+3+3
#If the input is 3, the output will be 12

num = int(input("Num: "))

for x in range(2):
    num += num

print(num)
```

Using an app called "Easy Coder" and
for some reason, the code above is not correct.

Is there a better way to do this? so the actual process of the code is("3+3+3+3) and not(3+3) + (3+3)

**Edit:** Sorry, I forgot to mention, that this is an exercise related to
looping.
The task:

> Write a program that uses a for loop to calculate any
> number X 4. 
> Hint - Add the number to a variable 4 times.

Comment: What's the difference between `(3+3+3+3)` and `(3+3) + (3+3)`? Addition is associative.

Comment: Use a separate variable for the total and initialize it to zero, then do `total += num` in the loop. The way you have it now, the second time through the loop, `num` is six, so `num += num` adds six rather than three.

Comment: The better way to do this is to do `3*4`, which doesn't involve any looping

Comment: In python you can use simple math operators. so simply `print(num*4)` would be enough. The for loop you are having there will not work because you hardcoded the range in which it will run. I guess you should start with the simple solution, I provided.

Comment: EDIT!: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that this is an exercise related to looping. The task:" Write a program that uses a for loop to calculate any number X 4. Hint - Add the number to a variable 4 times.

Comment: Hey, your code works perfectly well, although doubling the double is an unusual way to multiply by 4. Maybe your app didn't expect _that_ answer, but is wasn't wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add 4 times, use a separate variable for the total and loop 4 times instead of twice

```
num = int(input("Num: "))
total = 0

for _ in range(4):
    total += num

print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you!

Sorry everyone for not explaining correctly :/

Answer (score -1):

You can always create another variable to store the total, or you could simply multiply the number initially by 4 instead of using a loop. Otherwise, like you said, your code is actually doing:

```
3 + 3 = 6
6 + 6 = 12
```

since you overwrite the initially supplied number.

Comment: @Barmar edited, I meant in terms of if you were to try to "add the number 3 times" as the problem asks.

Comment: "You can always create another variable" - I don't see any variables in your answer.

Comment: The exercise is clearly intended to teach looping, not multiplication.